# How can i validate my form (AJAX)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I made this code for validate my form (ajax), but it doesn't work,(doesn't execute the `Checkpage` function).

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    function Checkpage(catego){
        var desc=$('#descripcion').val();
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var parametros = {"descripcion":desc,"title":title};
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'Check.php',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#Checkpage").html("...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                if(response!=" "){
                    alert(response);                                                                                                           
                } else { 
                    alert('Process');
                    $("#myform").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

please help me

Comment: So... you are going to submit your values once for validation, then submit them again if they are valid? Why not just do the validation on the submit?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't executing the function?  Throw in a `console.log('test');` above `var desc=$('#descripcion').val();`.  Also, click F12 in Google Chrome and go to the network panel to see what happened to your AJAX request.

Comment: I want to make the validation first and then submit. @ElGuapo

Answer (score 0):

All your submit function currently does is just declare a function named `Checkpage()` it does not call it.  Just remove the `Checkpage()` function declaration altogether and have the rest of the code run directly in `submit()` function.

Then of course, you need to NOT call `submit()` recursively.  What you need to do is return `true` for cases where the validation passes to allow the submit to perform its intended action or return `false` to prevent the form from submitting.

I order to do this however, you are going to need to actually wait for the result from the ajax call before returning the true/false response as this call is asynchronous.  One way to do this would be to make the call a blocking synchronous call using `async: false`.  You can then set a flag to indicate the POST is valid and return the value of the flag.

So what you end up with might look like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    var validationSuccess = false;
    var desc=$('#descripcion').val();
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var parametros = {"descripcion":desc,"title":title};
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   'Check.php',
        type:  'post',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#Checkpage").html("...");
        },
        success:  function (response) {
            if(response == " ") {
                // this is valid request
                valdidationSuccess = true;
            }
        }      
    });
    return validationSuccess;
});
```

Comment: Would he (or she) need to make this ajax call synchronously? Returning "true" or "false" from success will only apply to the "success method" A method variable declared in event function will need to be created and set within "success"